# Mysql problem in exporting data

Tags: mysql, export

I am using mysql and trying to export database through below command

mysqldump -uroot -p -d database_name > file.sql

It ran successfully.
However it did not export the data, it only export the schema of database.

anyone know why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [mysqldump documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data):

> --no-data, -d
>
> Do not write any table row information (that is, do not dump table contents). This is useful >if you want to dump only the CREATE TABLE statement for the table (for example, to create an >empty copy of the table by loading the dump file).

Try removing the `-d` from your command line.